# Changing a variable of function from another script

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I have a question. I have 2 script files on Unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

public class CycleFinal : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Lights
    public Light2D GlobLight;
    public Light2D SptLight;

    //Displays
    public Text timeDisplay;
    public Text moveDisplay;
    public Text phaseDisplay;

    //Others
    [SerializeField]
    public float cdTimer = 20f;
    public float moveCount = 20f;


    void Start()
    {
        timeDisplay.GetComponent<Text>();
        moveDisplay.GetComponent<Text>();
        phaseDisplay.GetComponent<Text>();
        moveCount = 0f;
        DayTime();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        cdTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(cdTimer <0){
            NightTime();
        }else if(moveCount <0){
            DayTime();
        }
        timeDisplay.text = "Day Time left: " + Mathf.Round(cdTimer);
        moveDisplay.text = "Movement left: " + Mathf.Round(moveCount);
    }

    public void DayTime(){
        phaseDisplay.text = "Day";
        
        SptLight.intensity = 0;
        GlobLight.intensity = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
    }

    public void NightTime(){
        phaseDisplay.text = "Night";

        SptLight.intensity = 1;
        GlobLight.intensity = 0;
        moveCount = 20;
        cdTimer = 0;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CycleFinal script;

    private PlayerMovement controls;   

    [SerializeField]
    private Tilemap groundTilemap;
    
    [SerializeField]
    private Tilemap collisionTilemap;



    private void Awake() {
        controls = new PlayerMovement();
    }

    private void OnEnable() {
        controls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        controls.Disable();
    }


    void Start()
    {
        controls.Main.Movement.performed += ctx => Move(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>());

    }

    private void Move(Vector2 direction){
        if(CanMove(direction))
            transform.position += (Vector3)direction;  
    }

    private bool CanMove(Vector2 direction){
        Vector3Int gridPosition = groundTilemap.WorldToCell(transform.position + (Vector3)direction);
        if(!groundTilemap.HasTile(gridPosition) || collisionTilemap.HasTile(gridPosition) || script.moveCount <= 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
            
    }
    

}
```

I am trying to decrease moveCount variable on every move my character made. (I'm planing to do this thing on PlayerController script Move function.) I accomplished this while moveCount variable is a variable outside of the NightTime function but when I move that moveCount variable in to the NightTime function I couldn't change its value. How can I do that?

Also main thing I want to do with those 2 script is the player will have x seconds of day time and x moves on nighttime when x seconds ends the game turns into night time and when x moves ends the game turns into day time.

Comment: `timeDisplay.GetComponent<Text>();` and the two functions after it don't do anything useful since you don't use the return value. It isn't clear what you're expecting those to do.

Comment: Yes I forgot to delete them I was using it before but not anymore. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: The assignment of __moveCount__ to either 0/20 inside **DayTime/NightTime** methods should happen only once since the call to this method is happening via **Update** method, which is updating its value to either 0/20 at every frame.

Comment: @nIcEcOw Thank you for the info what I've done so far I merged both scripts into one I didn't want to pull vars from other scripts. Also I moved moveCount variable from night time function to

`        
if(cdTimer <0){
            NightTime();
            moveCount = 20f; 
`

here so it is on the update function now. But still I am having the same problem.